# Error with WSO2 ESB when trying to connect to Jira and ElasticSearch

Tags: wso2, jira-rest-api, wso2-esb

I have and scenario where I want to extract dynamically Issues from Jira in order to save them on ElasticSearch. I use a custom Proxy Service that connect with Jira (via Jira connector), get a project (first I want to save the project's information) and pass this information to Elastic. Following is the in Sequence of the proxy service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property expression="json-eval($.username)" name="username"/>
<property expression="json-eval($.password)" name="password"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.uri)" name="uri"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.id)" name="id"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.uriEl)" name="uriEl"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.indexName)" name="indexName"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.type)" name="type"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.message)" name="message"/>
    <jira.init>
        <username>{$ctx:username}</username>
        <password>{$ctx:password}</password>
        <uri>{$ctx:uri}</uri>
    </jira.init>
    <jira.getProject>
        <projectIdOrKey>{$ctx:id}</projectIdOrKey>
    </jira.getProject>
    <property expression="json-eval($.project)" name="project"
    scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <elasticsearch.init>
        <apiUrl>{$ctx:uriEl}</apiUrl>
    </elasticsearch.init>
    <elasticsearch.createDocumentWithIndex>
        <indexName>{$ctx:indexName}</indexName>
        <type>{$ctx:type}</type>
        <message>{$ctx:message}</message>
        <body>{$ctx:project}</body>
     </elasticsearch.createDocumentWithIndex>
    <respond/>
</inSequence>
```

And here is the sample request:

```
{
    "username":"MyName",
    "password":"AnStrongPassword",       
    "uri":"JiraURL",        
    "id":"MyProject",
    "uriEl":"http://localhost:9200",
    "indexName":"jira",
    "type":"project",
    "message":"Testing" 
}
```

The other parameters (Endpoint, out Sequence and Fault Sequence) are by default.

The problem is that when I try to send this request via 'Try the Test service' option on WSO2 ESB, i get the following error:

> Error connecting to the Tryit ajax proxy

I have tested the same code but only using the Jira connection (without get a project or connect to Elastic), and the same error occurs.

Looking to this error, I suppose that the problem is before to read the JSON request, but I don't know if it is related to the endpoint (I think that it is not necessary an endpoint for this scenario).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please first test through postman or some other RestClient, for the connectors, TryIt tool will not get success always because you need to send headers also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is totally independent of the jira connector etc. Problem is with the "try it" tool. This tool is not that much recommended for testing purposes. Instead of that, try invoking the proxy service via soap ui.

If you share a screenshot when the try it error occurs, I'll be able to comment on that as well.

Comment: Thank you Amila, I have solved the problema using Soap UI.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days I have found another solution to my problem without using proxy services. To connect ESB with Jira, I created this API on ESB:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="transport_service" context="/transport_service">
<resource methods="GET">
  <inSequence>
     <jira.init>
        <uri>MyURL</uri>
        <username>MyUser</username>
        <password>3MyPass</password>
     </jira.init>
     <jira.searchJira>
        <query>project=MyProject</query>
        <maxResults>50000</maxResults>
        <fields>MyField1,MyField2,etc</fields>
     </jira.searchJira>
     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
</resource>
</api>
```

The command to call this API is simple:

```
curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8280/transport_service > jira-db.json
```

Finally, if you want to insert this json on elastic, you can follow the typical PUT via curl:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/jira/jira/1' -d @jira-db.json
```

Additionally, you can write both commands on a daily bash script (using your scheduled task list), getting the same result that scheduling your proxy service on WSO2ESB:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8280/transport_service > jira-db.json
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/jira-dev/jira/1' -d @jira-db.json
echo "Daily load completed"
```